# Is it possible to have both tls and mtls for different paths on the same host in nginx ingress controller?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, ssl, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I have some services in azure AKS currently that I would like to expose with my NGINX ingress controller. Some of them however use client certificates for authorization. Is it possible to expose services with regular tls and those that require client certificates under the same host but on different paths, or do I need to have a separate host for those with mtls?

Until now, I tried to add those annotations in one of my ingress resources:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: dev2/ingress-cert-azure
but with no luck.